# react material table export button not view correct

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

[in my react use export button material table not show complete bar my code i use the source code in material table:

options=
{{exportButton:true }}
how solvet it? ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeL2X.png)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to open up the toolbar to view the export button.

```
toolbar: true,        
exportButton: true,
```

Answer (score 0):

My export settings are:

```
options={{
        exportButton: true,
        exportAllData: true,  // optional
      }}
```

Don't forget to add:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon family=Material+Icons" />
```

In the header of your:

```
public/index.html
```

source: [docs](https://material-table.com/#:%7E:text=table%20icons%20prop.-,HTML,-%3Clink)