# MaterialTable Export option not showing?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

For some reason my material-table stopped showing export option

[image]

I did some updates on my app to catch up to material-ui v5 cause I was having some issues and material-table is not compatible with v5 but there was like a "patch" (forgot name) to make it work and is working but no longer has the export option ? any help is appreciate it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62892732/react-material-table-export-button-not-view-correct Set toolbar: true in options

Comment: it wasn't that, it was a conflict with another version but thanks for that :3